# css file isn't being recognized

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a very new site I am trying to put together and it seems that my css file isn't being recognized.

The site is http://www.problemio.com and I have in my index.php a direction to pick up the css file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
```

and then a header div declaration like this where some of the initial styles are used:

```
<?php
include("divs/header.php");
?>
```

I am trying to go through the index.php file with firebug, but not sure how to tell if the css file is being recognized or something else is the problem.

Any ideas how to get the styles recognized?

Comment: I am able to load your CSS file. Your CSS file is also valid ([validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)). At which browser are you experiencing issues?

Comment: The CSS file is loading... What is leading you to think that it's not?  Is there a certain style you think should be showing up, but isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Loaded CSS:
>
> > grids-min.css
> >
> > main.css
> >
> > menusystem.css
> >
> > reset-min.css

Reset is loading after the others, which nullifies the majority of your settings.

Comment: Just tried it and its still not working. Anything else that can be the solution?

Comment: It looks like it's working fine. What are the desired effects that you're not getting?

Answer (score 4):

You have to link to the CSS Reset before you link to your own styles.

The way you set it up now, the CSS Reset is resetting your styles.

Change this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/reset/reset-min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/grids/grids-min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menusystem.css"/>
```

to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/reset/reset-min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/grids/grids-min.css"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menusystem.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
```

Comment: I just did that change, and it is still not working.  Any idea what else it can be?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because of the order you are loading the CSS files. You are loading your "main.css" file first, then the YUI reset CSS, which basically resets whatever your main.css file has set already. Try loading the reset first.

Comment: I just changed the order of the css declarations and it is still not working.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

The stylesheet appears to be loading fine.  You need to put it after the reset styles though, or the reset will get rid of most of yours.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/reset/reset-min.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.8.2r1/build/grids/grids-min.css"></link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menusystem.css"/>
```

If the problem you think you are seeing is related to the sign-in links, note that they are set to `color:#fff;`, which happens to match the background...

Depending on your browser, Ctrl+Shift+I (Chrome), Ctrl+Alt+I (Safari), F12 (IE9), or Firebug (Firefox) can show you which resources are loaded... You should probably get comfortable with the developer modes for each.

Comment: Just did that and it is still not working.  Any clue what else may be the problem?